# Setting the scroll back to its position

Tags: android

So I have this app where I get the next question in an activity and I have a scroll for it which is working just fine.. the problem is when I get the next question the scroll will be in its previous position..how do I set it back to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using ScrollView, you can use [scrollTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) or [smoothScrollTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo%28int,%20int%29):

```
myScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
```